# Can see the billing report only for one project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I have
Compute Network Admin
Editor
OwnerSecurity Center Admin Viewer

roles assigned.

When I go to the billing reports page. I am not able to see the report for all projects, but only for the project which I select. In the projects filter(All projects) at the right hand pane I see the current project all selected by default and I cant see any other projects.

I need to give the report for all the projects. Is there anything I am missing?

also in the left hand side i can see only three options as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbGlZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see.
Go to Reports.
Then right hand side you have filter to check billing by project,services etc

Please find below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi. I am able to see only one project in the drop down. There are many other projects and i need to select that project to see the details, not consolidated

Comment: Hi , You need to check the billing account you selected at left top. These project might be in another billing account.

Comment: all same billing account

Comment: then you are not owner for all the project.

Comment: atleast i should be able to select the projects for which im the owner? I can select only one project.

Comment: you able to select a project at top project browser, but when you are in billing section you will be able to see projects for which you are the owner. if you ever noticed , if you go to billing tab there wont be any project, as Billing is org level resource.